# Traefik routing to two ports in one docker container

Tags: docker, web-server, docker-compose

I want to serve two web servers from a single docker container, and expose them through two ports using a Traefik proxy server.

I found [an example](https://github.com/donkirkby/traefik-two-ports/tree/two-app-containers) docker compose file that serves two web servers from *two separate* docker containers:

```
version: "3"

services:

  # The `proxy` service set up two entrypoints (read that as
  # "listeners") for traefik, one on port 80 and one on port 9090.
  proxy:
    image: traefik:latest
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker
      - --entrypoints.ep1.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.ep2.address=:9090

    # We need to publish ports 80 and 9090. Here I'm also
    # publishing port 8080, which is the Traefik dashboard, but
    # that's not necessary.
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  # We bind container `app1` to entrypoint `ep1`, with a `Host`
  # rule matching `example.com`. I'm setting `...server.port` here
  # because the `darkhttpd` container listens on port 8080.
  app1:
    image: docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd:latest
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./www80
        target: /var/www/localhost/htdocs
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.services.app1.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
      - traefik.http.routers.app1.rule=Host(`example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.app1.entrypoints=ep1

  # We bind container `app2` to entrypoint `ep2`, with a `Host`
  # rule matching `example.com`.
  app2:
    image: docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd:latest
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/don/Documents/docker-test/www9090
        target: /var/www/localhost/htdocs
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.services.app2.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
      - traefik.http.routers.app2.rule=Host(`example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.app2.entrypoints=ep2
```

I added `example.com` to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       example.com
```

That works fine when I request `http://example.com` and `http://example.com:9090`, but how can I serve two ports from a *single* container?

I tried just launching the two servers from the same container with a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

darkhttpd /var/www/localhost/htdocs9090 --port 9090 &

darkhttpd /var/www/localhost/htdocs --port 8080
```

Then I [combined](https://github.com/donkirkby/traefik-two-ports/tree/one-app-container-broken) the two container definitions:

```
version: "3"

services:

  # The `proxy` service set up two entrypoints (read that as
  # "listeners") for traefik, one on port 80 and one on port 9090.
  proxy:
    image: traefik:latest
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker
      - --entrypoints.ep1.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.ep2.address=:9090

    # We need to publish ports 80 and 9090. Here I'm also
    # publishing port 8080, which is the Traefik dashboard, but
    # that's not necessary.
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  # We bind container `app1` to both entrypoints `ep1` and `ep2`, with a `Host`
  # rule matching `example.com`. The launch script launches two darkhttpd
  # processes that listen on ports 8080 and 9090.
  app1:
    image: docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd:latest
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: www80
        target: /var/www/localhost/htdocs
      - type: bind
        source: www9090
        target: /var/www/localhost/htdocs9090
      - type: bind
        source: launcher
        target: /var/www/localhost/launcher
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.services.app1.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
      - traefik.http.routers.app1.rule=Host(`example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.app1.entrypoints=ep1
      - traefik.http.services.app2.loadbalancer.server.port=9090
      - traefik.http.routers.app2.rule=Host(`example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.app2.entrypoints=ep2
    entrypoint: /var/www/localhost/launcher/launch.sh
```

When I run `docker compose`, it complains that there are too many services:

```
traefik-two-ports-proxy-1  | time="2023-12-22T23:35:03Z" level=error msg="Could not define the service name for the router: too many services" routerName=app2 providerName=docker
```

How can I combine the services into one container without upsetting docker?

Answer (score 3):

After some searching, I found that you need to [explicitly name](https://github.com/donkirkby/traefik-two-ports/tree/main) the services when there's more than one in a container.

```
version: "3"

services:

  # The `proxy` service set up two entrypoints (read that as
  # "listeners") for traefik, one on port 80 and one on port 9090.
  proxy:
    image: traefik:latest
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker
      - --entrypoints.ep1.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.ep2.address=:9090

    # We need to publish ports 80 and 9090. Here I'm also
    # publishing port 8080, which is the Traefik dashboard, but
    # that's not necessary.
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  # We bind container `app1` to both entrypoints `ep1` and `ep2`, with a `Host`
  # rule matching `example.com`. The launch script launches two darkhttpd
  # processes that listen on ports 8080 and 9090.
  # When a service container holds more than one service, you have to explicitly
  # name the service for each router.
  app1:
    image: docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd:latest
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: www80
        target: /var/www/localhost/htdocs
      - type: bind
        source: www9090
        target: /var/www/localhost/htdocs9090
      - type: bind
        source: launcher
        target: /var/www/localhost/launcher
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.services.app1.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
      - traefik.http.routers.app1.service=app1
      - traefik.http.routers.app1.rule=Host(`example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.app1.entrypoints=ep1
      - traefik.http.services.app2.loadbalancer.server.port=9090
      - traefik.http.routers.app2.service=app2
      - traefik.http.routers.app2.rule=Host(`example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.app2.entrypoints=ep2
    entrypoint: /var/www/localhost/launcher/launch.sh
```

Now, I can hit both `http://example.com` and `http://example.com:9090` again, while only running one web server container.